# generalizations of continuous operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

What are generalizations of the notion of continous linear operator $P:X\to X$, where X is a Banach space?

I'm looking for some broader class of operators that nevertheless share some properties of continous mappings.

In real functions, there are semicontinous functions, consecutive Baire classes or Darboux functions. Any useful notion of this kind for linear Banach space operators?

Comment: The most natural generalization is the notion of a densely defined closed operator.

Comment: Or you could relax linearity instead of continuity, e.g., consider continuous maps that are degree $1$ homogeneous but not necessarily linear. Or Lipschitz continuous, to be more specific.

Comment: Unfortunately, in my case I can't. I will try with closed operators. Or take two topologies in X, saying that "if $x_n$ converges "strongly" to x, then $P x_n$ converges "weakly" to $Px$. Both ideas are very problematic though.